# Python strings - strange replacing behavior

Tags: python, mysql, string

I have a function, where I get a string as parameter. I want to save this string to a database. So I have a command like:

```
    sql_command = """INSERT INTO some_table(some_text_row) VALUE (
        '{0}');""".format(some_text)
```

But the parameter can contain characters like `'`. So I need to replace this sort of characters. I do this with this function:

```
    some_text = given_parameter.replace("'", r"\'")
```

But now comes the strange behavior: Sometimes, I get a result of `\\'` and sometimes I get a result of `\'`. I want to have the second one.

To give you more information: The `given_parameter` is the HTML code of a webpage. I get the HTML code from the library called `requests`

Does anyone have some tipps?

Comment: FWIW, usually you don't want to do your own string interpolation in sql_commands -- It potentially opens you up to [sql injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't construct the query using string formatting** - this is unsafe, you are making it vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Instead, **parameterize the query** and let the mysql driver worry about quotes:

```
sql_command = """
    INSERT INTO 
        some_table(some_text_row) 
    VALUES 
        (%s)"""
cursor.execute(sql_command, (some_text, ))
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the solution.